# Convert dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to convert a date in format dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd
For example, if the date is 04.12.2020, i want it to be like 2020-12.04(which is 4th december)
But the command giving me the output as 2020-04-12( which is 12th April)
**select convert(date,'04.12.2020' )**

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `str_to_date()`:

```
select str_to_date('04.12.2020', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a date as a string? (ie. the "04.12.2020").
MySql has a STR_TO_DATE() function:

```
select str_to_date('04.12.2020', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

That should convert it to an actual date datatype.

If needed an actual date can then be formated in which ever way you want or just visualized depending on what you're trying to do with DATE_FORMAT():

```
select date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```